# xml schema adding a Range to a attribute and textblock

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I am new to xml schemas, and i have a project for school to make a chess board schema. 
Things are going good. and i suppose i could parse this with c# to make sure it is all valid, But i would rather the schema catch the issue. 
So here is the issue

i have an xml document that is taking the pieces and making them have a modifier and a location

```
<pieces>
    <black>
      <!--Pawns-->
      <piece modifier="P">17</piece>
      <piece modifier="P">27</piece>
      <piece modifier="P">37</piece>
      <piece modifier="P">47</piece>
      <piece modifier="P">57</piece>
      <piece modifier="P">67</piece>
      <piece modifier="P">77</piece>
      <piece modifier="P">87</piece>

      <!--Rooks-->
      <piece modifier="R">18</piece>
      <piece modifier="R">88</piece>

      <!--Knights-->
      <piece modifier="N">28</piece>
      <piece modifier="N">78</piece>

      <!--Bishops-->
      <piece modifier="B">38</piece>
      <piece modifier="B">68</piece>

      <!--Royalty-->
      <piece modifier="Q">48</piece>
      <piece modifier="K">58</piece>
    </black>
</pieces>
```

there is a few things i would like to do, but i don't know how to go about it, I want to verify that the integer value is not below 11, and not above 88. This is what i have now. I have looked at other stack overflow posts for similar topics, but i couldn't find one that worked.

```
<xs:element name="black">
  <xs:complexType>
     <xs:sequence>

        <xs:element name="piece" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="16">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:simpleContent>
               <xs:extension base="xs:integer">
                  <xs:attribute name="modifier" type="xs:string"/>
               </xs:extension>
            </xs:simpleContent>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element><!--End Piece-->

    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element><!--End black-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to declare a new simple type and then apply the extension with that simpleType as base.

This would then look like this:

```
<xs:element name="black">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="piece" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="16">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="BlackModifiedPiece">
              <xs:attribute name="modifier" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:extension>
          </xs:simpleContent>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:simpleType name="BlackModifiedPiece">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:int">
    <xs:minInclusive value="11"/>
    <xs:maxInclusive value="88"/>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Hope this is helpful ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes when XSD doesn't let you do what you want, there is a reason. For example, your values such as 67 and 82 are not really integers, because they are not amenable to integer operations like subtraction. They are actually pairs of digits in the range 1-8. So you might be better off identifying squares on the board in the way that is standard in modern chess notation ("algebraic notation") e.g. h1 or e5. Then you could describe this in XSD as a string restricted with a regular expression `<xsd:pattern value="[a-h][1-8]"/>`. (Of course you could also use strings restricted to "[1-8][1-8]", but in my view that would be confusing).

If you want to start expressing the semantic rules of chess in your schema, e.g. by having rules that you can't have more than eight pawns of each colour and that pawns can't be on the back row, then you'll need to start using XSD 1.1 assertions.